# VBA Excel - Formatting YEAR RANGE using validation

Tags: excel, vba

Just want to ask if it is possible to input a year range in a textbox? My idea is that when the user types the first 4 numbers, it automatically displays the dash with the year for the following year. For example, when a user types `2020` into the text box or after the fourth number, the `-2021` will automatically display.

Here's the current code that I've been working on.

```
If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then
   If Len(tb.Text) = 9 Then KeyAscii = 0               
      If tb.SelStart = 0 Then
           If KeyAscii < 49 Or KeyAscii > 50 Then KeyAscii = 0
           ElseIf tb.SelStart = 4 Or tb.SelStart = 5 Then
               If KeyAscii < 49 Or KeyAscii > 51 Then
                  KeyAscii = 0
               Else
                  tb.Text = Left(tb.Text, 4) & "-" & CInt(tb.Text + 1)
               End If
           End If
Else
    KeyAscii = 0
End If
```

**UPDATE:** The `-2021` is now showing, but the problem is I need to input the 5th number first before the `-2021` appears. Plus, the fifth number that I enter appears in the last part of the value.

For example, I input `2020` in the textbox. I need to enter one more number so that the `-2021` will appear and after that, the value became `2020-20213`. The `3` is the number that I entered before `-2021` appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I made.

```
tb.MaxLength = 9     
If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then 'This textbox only allows for numbers 0-9
  If Len(tb.Text) = 9 Then KeyAscii = 0        
     If tb.SelStart = 0 Then
       If KeyAscii < 49 Or KeyAscii > 50 Then KeyAscii = 0     
          ElseIf tb.SelStart = 4 Then
          If KeyAscii < 49 Or KeyAscii > 51 Then
               KeyAscii = 0
          Else
              tb.Text = Left(tb.Text, 4) & "-" & CInt(tb.Text + 1)
          End If
        End If
Else
   KeyAscii = 0
End If
```

- `CInt(tb.Text + 1)` - add plus one to the year
- `tb.MaxLength = 9` - the maximum number of characters a user can enter. Using this code, it solved the last number issue.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the textbox's `Change` event to respond to user input. In the code below, when the length of the input is 4 characters, and if the input is a number, it automatically appends a "-" and the next year. It also selects the next year so that a user can easily overwrite the default value.

Is this helpful?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim sInput As String
    
    sInput = TextBox1.Value
    
    If Len(sInput) <> 4 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If IsNumeric(sInput) Then
        TextBox1.Value = sInput & "-" & (CInt(sInput) + 1)
        TextBox1.SelStart = 5
        TextBox1.SelLength = 4
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to validate more than one textbox that's why I'm using the `Class` file. I used this `sInput & "-" & (CInt(sInput) + 1)` in my codes and it helps, but I'm still having a problem. When I typed the fifth number, the value became `2020-20212`. The 2 in the last value is the one that I entered before the `2021` appears.